# Error: Template Directory Not Found

Tags: php, git, codeigniter, wamp

I have cloned a git repo that someone made for a CodeIgniter website. I have a WAMP server set up fine in my computer and it works fine. In the Apache modules I enable the `rewrite_module` and in the PHP Settings I enable `short open tag`. I also put my database settings in the `application\config\database.php` file. After that, I put the CodeIgniter folder in the `C:\wamp\www\CodeIgniter` folder.

Now the problem is that when I go to `localhost/CodeIgniter` I get this:

```
Error: Template Directory Not Found!
```

I have looked for several hours online for this error but I could not find anything similar. If someone has seen this error before and knows how to solved it I will really appreciate any help or if you could point me in the right direction since I am new to CodeIgniter.

Comment: You'll just need to debug this - there could be plenty of reasons for it. Does the repo also contain CI, or is just code that uses the CI framework? Perhaps you need to get that separately? If you use the line number and file mentioned in your error (do you see these?) then that may show you where to start looking. Also, CI may have a "debug mode" - if so, enable it, and it may offer you on-screen logs to show you what happened inside a request.

Comment: @halfer thanks for your comment...the error does not show any line numbers or anything else. I will look at trying to see how to debug in CI since I have never done that.

Comment: Look at the config somewhere for php error and change that to development ( if i'm guessing right... it's been a while back ). That way you can see the error...

Comment: Do you believe that CI is correctly installed? Also, check your PHP logs.

Comment: @halfer yes is correct because someone in my team is using it...I change log_errors = On in the php.ini file and also error_log = c:/wamp/logs/php_error.log but I don't see anything in the logs file.

Comment: That's not in itself evidence that the repo will work by itself, imo. Check with your colleague to see if they had to separately download, install or configure CodeIgniter to work with this web app.

Comment: Open the Index.php and search where they define `ENVIRONMENT` and set that to `development`. That way you should get the errors...

Comment: @Mathlight it is set to development... `define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');`

Comment: @0gravity, mayby this helps: [link](http://williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/reference.html)
Read the part `Setting the Default Template`, mayby is that the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like your app is using a third-party Template library, and a config is incorrect

Search your application dir for "Template Directory Not Found" - that will take you to where the error message is in the code, and you can then figure out what library is calling it. Or, take a look in your application/config - most likely there's a file for it

"Template Directory Not Found" is not part of Codeigniter.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the suggestion...the problem was because of a third_party library that the path was missing a slash before the directory name.